# ¿Por qué el cifrado de los archivos zip es tan débil ante ataques de fuerza bruta?

Tags: seguridad, zip

Estoy aprendiendo pentesting con el libro "Violent Python" (muy recomendado) y uno de los ejercicios es generar un script para atacar por fuerza bruta a un archivo ZIP encriptado con una contraseña.

El script funciona muy bien cuando se trata de una encriptación **ZIP 2.0 (portable)** (Los algoritmos 128-Bit AES y 256-Bit AES son más seguros y se demora mas en encontrarlo). El tema es que no solo encuentra rápidamente la contraseña cuando se usa un diccionario, sino que también encuentra más de una contraseña válida y eso si que no lo entiendo y me es necesario saber porqué sucede esto.

El código usado es el siguiente:

1. Archivo ZIP encriptado con la contraseña: **yoda**
2. Archivo TXT con 2300 palabras sueltas
3. Script utilizado:

   ```
   import zipfile
   from threading import Thread

   def extractFile(zFile, password):
       try:
           zFile.extractall(pwd=password)
           print '[+] Found password ' + password + '\n'
       except:
           pass

   def main():
       zFile = zipfile.ZipFile('archivo.zip')
       passFile = open('passwords.txt')

       for line in passFile.readlines():
           password = line.strip('\n')
           t = Thread(target=extractFile, args=(zFile, password))
           t.start()

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
   ```
4. Resultado

   ```
   >>> 
   [+] Found password Carrie
   [+] Found password cocacola
   [+] Found password eagle1
   [+] Found password jean
   [+] Found password panda
   [+] Found password Grover
   [+] Found password cfi
   [+] Found password beautifu
   [+] Found password yoda <- lo puse al final del diccionario 
   >>>
   ```

Como se puede observar encuentra más de una contraseña y lo peor de todo que todas estas contraseñas funcionan. Es decir es posible desencriptar el archivo ZIP con cualquiera de estas contraseñas.

Con el fin de investigar más, la preguntas son:

- ¿Qué algoritmo usa ZIP para esta encriptación?
- ¿Cómo es posible descifrarse con más de una contraseña?

Comment: Hola, acabo de replicar tu caso y no me sucede lo mismo. ¿Cómo estás encriptándo el archivo y desde qué plataforma?

Comment: @César Estoy en Win2 8.1 Zip Versión Pro 10.0 ( Antiguo ) y te dejo los archivos en mi dropbox [ https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/44676047/archivos.zip ] donde se  encuentran los archivos. ( El archivo Zip contiene un archivo txt vacío)

Comment: Primero he intentado sin tocar nada y paso lo que mencionas, luego el archivo `secreto.txt` le puse el mismo password y lo comprimi desde Linux y el script corre correctamente. Creo que el problema es tu herramienta de encriptación. En otras pruebas, esto solo pasa cuando el archivo está vacío, si pones contenido en el archivo me funciona bien.

Comment: Muy Interesante lo que planteas, lo probe y claro solo reconoce la contraseña correcta. Ahora, quiero aclarar que no estoy usando alguna herramienta de encriptación solo le pongo la contraseña al archivo ZIP y mi pregunta no apunta a solucionar un problema que tenga, sino más bien a entender este suceso, saber por qué pasa esto.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Que varias contraseñas puedan descodificar no significa que todas sean válidas (https://security.stackexchange.com/q/33081/13877). Sólo la verdadera contraseña dará un resultado coherente al descomprimir, si usas las demás el resultado será archivos sin sentido, pero el script no puede distinguir archivos con sentido de archivos cuyo contenido sea basura, por eso te da varias contraseñas como válidas.

Cualquier contraseña corta será fácil de romper con un ataque de fuerza bruta, y cualquier contraseña que sea una palabra común será fácil de romper con un ataque de diccionario (lo que estás haciendo es más bien un ataque de diccionario, no de fuerza bruta). La contraseña "yoda" sería fácil de romper sea cual sea el sistema de cifrado, no sólo en un zip.

Comment: Hice la comprobación con una contraseña más fuerte y con un archivo TXT con texto. Efectivamente la desencripta pero no es posible leer el contenido. La explicación que da Nick en el comentario de la respuesta aceptada (del link que enviaste) es clarísima. Gracias.